# My Z axis isn't moving when I home it but it moves on TFT display and Pronterface

Tags: marlin, skr-v1.4, tmc2209, tronxy, tronxy-x5sa

I'm using an SKR 1.4 turbo with a Tronxy X5SA 500 Pro, TMC2209 stepper drivers with the dialogue pins cut because I'm using physical limit switches instead of sensor-less homing. The Z-axis moves up and down fine.

When I try to home it it doesn't move. I don't know why. Everything else is working and I confirmed the limit switches work with the `M119` command. Someone please help. I'm certain it is in the firmware. I pulled the stepper driver for the Z and made sure it was clipped short enough. Actually, it's the shortest of all four. Also, I'm working with dual Z-limit switches. And I have an inductive Z probe on the nozzle. But I have disabled the probe in the software. My main goal is to home Z to the limit switches right now.

Does anyone have any ideas or commands I can run? I'm running the most recent stable version of Marlin.

Comment: What do you mean by `I pulled the stepper driver for the Z and made sure it was clipped short enough.` Also, why using an inductive probe and two limit switches?